# Is there a predefined bandpass filter block in tikz?

Tags: diagrams, circuitikz, block

[image]
I want to create this block diagram.

```
    \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 \usepackage{pst-solides3d}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
 \tikzset{
 state/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=6ex},
 arrow/.style={-latex, shorten >=1ex, shorten <=1ex}}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}  
 %antenne
  \draw (0,-2) -- (0,.75);
  \draw (-1,.75) -- (0,-.25) -- (1,.75);
  \draw
  (0,-2) -- (3,-2);
  %lna
  \draw
  (3,-2.5) -- (3,-1.5)
  (3,-1.5) -- (4,-2)
  (3,-2.5) -- (4,-2)
  ;
  \draw[-latex]
  (4,-2) -- (6,-2);
  %bf1
  \draw
  (6,-2.5) -- (6,-1.5) -- (7,-1.5) -- (7,-2.5)-- (6,-2.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any predefined bandpass filter in circuitikz and if don't how do I get the sinus curves into this little box?

Comment: There are some block examples in http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/noise-shaper/ and http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fir-filter/ you will be able to use.

Answer (score 6):

This is a `circuitikz` solution. Two blocks are defined for `bandpass filter` and `mixer` called, respectively,  `\BPF` and `\cross`. Both redefine AC voltage sources into a set of drawing commands to draw the symbols.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\newcommand{\cross}[1] 
{  % #1 = name , 
\draw[thick] (#1) circle (12pt);
\draw[rotate=45,line width=0.5pt]   (#1)  +(0,-12pt) -- +(0,12pt);
\draw[rotate=-45,line width=0.5pt]  (#1)  +(0,-12pt) -- +(0,12pt);
}

\newcommand{\BPF}[2] 
{  % #1 = name , #2 = rotation angle
\begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate=#2]
\draw[thick] (#1)node[](a){} +(-12pt,-12pt) rectangle +(12pt,12pt);
\draw (a) +(-8pt,0) to[bend left] +(0,0) edge[bend right] +(8pt,0);
\draw ([yshift=5pt]a) +(-8pt,0) to[bend left] +(0,0) to[bend right] +(8pt,0);
\draw ([yshift=-5pt]a) +(-8pt,0) to[bend left] +(0,0) edge[bend right] +(8pt,0);
\draw[rotate=20] ([yshift=5pt]a) +(-4pt,0) -- +(7pt,0);
\draw[rotate=20] ([yshift=-5pt]a) +(-7pt,0) -- +(4pt,0);
\end{scope}
}

\tikzset{ar/.style={-latex,shorten >=-1pt, shorten <=-1pt}}
\begin{document}  

\begin{circuitikz}
\path (4,0) node[above=2pt]() {LO} to[sV]node[pos=0,inner sep=0pt](b){} (4,2);
\draw (0,3) node[buffer,scale=0.8](buf){}
node[above =0.8 cm]{LNA};
\path (1,3) to[sV,color=white,name=bp]
node[pos=0,inner sep=0pt](d){}
node[above left=0.8cm and 0.2cm]{BPF} (3,3);
\BPF{bp}{0}
\path (4,2) to[sV,color=white,name=M1]node[midway,above=0.1cm]{Mixer}(4,4);
\cross{M1}
\draw[] (-1,3) node [antenna,xscale=-1] (A) {}--(buf.in);
\draw[ar] (bp)--(M1);
\draw[ar] (buf.out)--(bp);
\draw[ar] (b)--(M1);
\draw[ar] (M1) -- +(2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```